# Using jQuery Masonry IsAnimatedFromBottom

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

Currently when I append new items to my masonry container they are added in the top left corner and then fly into position. However, in [this example](http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/infinite-scroll.html) on the masonry website the new elements appear at the bottom.

It says in the demo description that the demo 'makes use of the IsAnimatedFromBottom flag', but looking at the code I can't see it:

```
<script> 
  $(function(){

    var $container = $('#container');

    $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
      $container.masonry({
        itemSelector: '.box',
        columnWidth: 100
      });
    });

    $container.infinitescroll({
      navSelector  : '#page-nav',    // selector for the paged navigation 
      nextSelector : '#page-nav a',  // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
      itemSelector : '.box',     // selector for all items you'll retrieve
      loading: {
          finishedMsg: 'No more pages to load.',
          img: 'http://i.imgur.com/6RMhx.gif'
        }
      },
      // trigger Masonry as a callback
      function( newElements ) {
        var $newElems = $( newElements );
        // ensure that images load before adding to masonry layout
        $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
          $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true ); 
        });
      }
    );

  });
</script>
```

Also looking at the listed [options](http://masonry.desandro.com/docs/options.html) it doesn't appear to be listed, so does anyone know how this is used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, always the way, found the answer as soon as I posted! The flag isn't a config setting, but a parameter for the appended method

```
.masonry( 'appended', $content, isAnimatedFromBottom)
```

Answer (score 3):

Was having some trouble with this myself. I think you actually want to set the flag to true so instead of

```
.masonry( 'appended', $content, isAnimatedFromBottom )
```

you would want

```
.masonry( 'appended', $content, true)
```